# Small float being saved in scientific notation instead of decimal

Tags: autoit, notation

When I try to declare a float variable with a very small value it changes the notation.

```
Global $interior = 0.00008972
MsgBox(4096, "1", $interior)
$file = FileOpen("Balance.txt", 2)
FileWrite($file, ""&$interior)
FileClose($file)
```

It shows and writes to file 8.972e-005 not 0.00008972.

Comment: They are the same floating point value - just normalized. (use this to confirm: https://web2.0calc.com/)  Output: guessing:  If you want to display it in a particular format  see: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFormat.htm ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringFormat to specify the precision you want for the float value.

```
Global $interior = 0.00008972
$interior = StringFormat("%.8f", $interior)
MsgBox(4096, "1", $interior)
$file = FileOpen("Balance.txt", 2)
FileWrite($file, ""&$interior)
FileClose($file)
```